# Radio button validation in Angular not working

Tags: angular, angular-forms

Html Code for radio button

```
<div class="form-group">
  <label>Gender</label>
  <div class="form-check" *ngFor="let gen of genderList">
    <input class="form-check-input" type="radio" ngModel name="gender" [value]="gen" #f_Gender="ngModel" required>&nbsp;
    <span class="form-check-label">{{gen}}</span>
  </div>
  <span class="text-danger" *ngIf="f_Gender.invalid && (f_Gender.touched || f_Gender.dirty)">Please select gender</span>
</div>
```

Property I have added to the typescript code.

```
genderList: string[] = ['Male', 'Female'];
```

The validation for the radio button is not working. It has to do something with the #f_Gender local reference I added to the page. Since the local reference is added twice on the page due to for loop. It is confusing angular. I'm getting the error `Cannot read property 'invalid' of undefined`. This means it is not creating the local reference or it is not accessible at the validation span tag.

Comment: #f_Gender="ngModel" ??? Are you sure if that's the right syntax?

Comment: Yes, the syntax is correct. I'm using it on the input text and select dropdown fields and, it is working fine.